# What is wrong if a wife rebukes her husband and(/or) does not watch over him

Tags: words, hebrew, shulchan-aruch, shalom-bayit

In this list

אם מקללתו בחנם או מזלזלת אביו ואמו והוכיחה בדברים ואינו משגחת עליו

(My translation "if she (the wife) curses him (the husband) without a reason, disrespects his parents, rebukes him with words, and does not watch over him)

of what a wife is not allowed to do I see

והוכיחה בדברים ואינו משגחת עליו

(rebukes him with words, and does not watch over him)

What does it mean? And what is wrong if she does it?

Comment: I'm stumped (and, perhaps, other readers are, too). Where does this phrase come from?

Comment: @DanF see Fred"s comment below EH 154:3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

והוכיחה בדברים ואינו משגחת עליו means *he* rebuked *her* with words and she pays him no heed.

Comment: This is regarding mitzot?

Comment: @hazoriz It's regarding the previously mentioned things; this is a case where a wife gratuitously curses her husband unprovoked or disparages his parents unprovoked, and he tells her not to do that but she disregards him and continues her aforementioned conduct.

Comment: Based on the quote, it sounds like in the case "*mezalzeles aviv v'imo*" the rule would apply even if she was provoked since it's only mentioned as a qualifier regarding if she curses *him*...

Comment: @loewian True, that's an interesting *diyuk* and a good point. On the other hand, the context there ([EH 154:3](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%93)) perhaps suggests that the Rama is referring to where her conduct is unprovoked in both cases. The equivalence of the two cases might be further supported by the Rama in [EH 115:4](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%95).

Comment: @Fred Show me the wife who isn't provoked by her mother-in-law!;) (Also, I still think the Rama may mean the lack of provocation is only necessary in the former case since he does reiterate it as the paradigm: "ואם היא מקללתו חנם" - the svara would be that *zilzul horav* can have no justification or quid pro quo)